# Sql Biggest error

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a problem in an SQL query. When we have to search more than one field we use the AND operator but when one of a fields is empty it shows no value.
E.g.:-

```
Select * from table_name 
where Party_name='"+ textbox.text &"' 
And No='"+ Textbox2.text &"'"
```

when one of field is empty it didn't show any value.plzz help me!!

Comment: Are you saying when a field is empty you don't want to filter on that field? Use some logic to identify that and don't add it to the SQL string when its empty

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can implement optional filters:

```
Dim sql = <sql>
              SELECT *
              FROM MyTable
              WHERE (@Column1A IS NULL OR Column1 = @Column1B)
              AND (@Column2A IS NULL OR Column2 = @Column2B)
          </sql>

command.CommandText = sql.Value

Dim filter1 = If(TextBox1.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), TextBox1.Text)
Dim filter2 = If(TextBox2.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), TextBox2.Text)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@Column1A", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = filter1
    .Add("@Column1B", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = filter1
    .Add("@Column2A", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = filter2
    .Add("@Column2B", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = filter2
End With
```

Firstly, note the use of the XML literal to make the SQL code more readable.  Secondly, note the use of parameters to insert values into the code rather than string concatenation.

As for the actual filtering, let's look at one pair of parameters:

```
@Column1A IS NULL OR Column1 = @Column1B
```

If `TextBox1` is empty then both `@Column1A` and `@Column1B` get set to `NULL`.  That means that the first condition is true and every row matches, effectively ignoring that filter.  If `TextBox1` is not empty then the first condition is false and only those rows for which the second condition is true will match, thus honouring that filter.

It's worth noting that you need four parameters because you're using Access.  The Jet and ACE OLE DB providers use positional parameters, even if you use names.  That means that one `OleDbParameter` cannot be used for more than one SQL parameter.  If you were using SQL Server then two parameters would be enough because each one could be used twice, i.e.

```
Dim sql = <sql>
              SELECT *
              FROM MyTable
              WHERE (@Column1 IS NULL OR Column1 = @Column1)
              AND (@Column2 IS NULL OR Column2 = @Column2)
          </sql>

command.CommandText = sql.Value

Dim filter1 = If(TextBox1.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), TextBox1.Text)
Dim filter2 = If(TextBox2.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), TextBox2.Text)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = filter1
    .Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = filter2
End With
```